# threaded comments using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table for insert comments data:(comments)

```
|id|message|timestamp|approved|parent_id|name|email|
```

and this table for insert reviews for comments:(reviews)

```
|id|cid|review_field1|review_field2|review_field3|...
```

php function :

```
function _comments_($id,$type){
    $DB = mySqli::f("SELECT id,name,email,message,timestamp,review_field_1,review_field_2,review_field_3  FROM " . NEWS_COMMENTS . " LEFT JOIN " . NEWS_REVIEWS . " ON " . NEWS_COMMENTS . ".id = " . NEWS_REVIEWS . ".cid WHERE 
    pid = ? AND type = ? AND approved = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 12", $id, $type);

        foreach($DB as $row){
         $commentdata[] = $row;
        }
    return $commentdata;
}
```

for result:

```
<?PHP
$comments_list = _comments_('125','news');
    foreach($comments_list as $row):
?>

        /// HTML tags
<?PHP 
    $endforeach;
?>
```

This worked for me and show list of comments and reviews for each comments.

Now i need to show *threaded comments*(`parent`) for each comment.

how do can i show threaded comments ?!

NOTE: for parent comment i dont send reviews.